# How to handle multiple observables when it doesn't matter if some fails?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have to subscribe to multiple observables when a page starts and I have to wait to have all the responses before starting. The first thing I saw was the forkjoin but it fails when one inner observable throws an error and I lose the value of the other observables.

I've made something like this and it works... but I'm sure that there is a better way:

```js
getResult(){
  let importantObservableResponse1
  let importantObservableResponse2
  let observableResponse3
  let observableResponse4

  return new Observable(obs => {
    this.firstObservable().subscribe(
      response => {
        importantObservableResponse1 = response
        if (importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse3, observableResponse4)
          obs.next([importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse3, observableResponse4])
      }, error => {
        let error = this.makeError(error)
        obs.error(error)
      }
    )

    this.secondObservable().subscribe(
      response => {
        importantObservableResponse2 = response
        if (importantObservableResponse1, observableResponse3, observableResponse4)
          obs.next([importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse3, observableResponse4])
      }, error => {
        let error = this.makeError(error)
        obs.error(error)
      }
    )

    this.thirdObservable().subscribe(
      response => {
        observableResponse3 = response
        if (importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse4)
          obs.next([importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse3, observableResponse4])
      }, error => {
        observableResponse3 = error
        if (importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse4)
          obs.next(error)
      }
    )

    this.fourthObservable().subscribe(
      response => {
        observableResponse4 = response
        if (importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse3)
          obs.next([importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse3, observableResponse4])
      }, error => {
        observableResponse4 = error
        if (importantObservableResponse1, importantObservableResponse2, observableResponse3)
          obs.next(error)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

I've put all my subscription in an observable and when I have all the information.

Is there a way at least to get all the responses at once even if some fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the order of the response matter? Can the responses be null or undefined?

If all you want to do is pump out an array of responses, have all the subscriptions be handled by the same thing, and I'd personally reconfigure the `getResult()` mechanism. Mostly because I'm not a fan of layering observables like that, feels too messy and hard to read.

What I mean by reconfigure: Have a result observable inintialised and sitting around that things can subscribe to rather than returning the observable as part of the `getResult()` method itself. That allows any number of things to subscribe to it and you can arbitrarily get/refresh the data and push said data to all those subscribers when it happens.

```
private resultObs: Observer<any[]>;
private resultResponses: any[];

private _result$: Observable<any[]>;

constructor() {
  this._result$ = new Observable<any[]>((x: Observer<any[]>) => { this.resultObs = x; }).pipe(share());
}

public get result$(): Observable<any[]> { return this._result$; }

// Method no longer returns anything, it's merely a triggering method
public getResult(): void {
  this.resultResponses= [];

  this.firstObservable().subscribe(x => this.handleResponse(1, x), err => this.handleError(1, err));

  this.secondObservable().subscribe(x => this.handleResponse(2, x), err => this.handleError(2, err));

  // ...
}


private handleResponse(order: number, response: any): void {
  // If order matters, handle relevant inserting here
  this.resultResponses.push(response);


  // Assuming you only want to emit when all 4 have come in successfully
  if (this.resultResponses.length === 4 && this.resultObs) {
    // Note: the this.resultObs check will ensure you don't get any errors
    // when trying to emit if nothing has subscribed to it yet...
    this.resultObs.next(this.resultResponses);
  }
}

private handleError(order: number, error: any): void {
  // Do whatever you need to do on failures
  console.error(error);
}
```

And whatever usage component you have for it:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  // Subscribe to the result observable
  this.service.result$.subscribe((x: any[]) => this.onResultResponse(x));

  // Trigger the retrieval of the data
  this.service.getResult();
}

private onResultResponse(data: any[]): void {
  // Handle your data now you've got it
  console.log('Got results:', data);
}
```

Edit: Fixed silly mistake with the value emit.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is something i was looking for!!! I am trying to implement it and i have problem with the line "this.result$.next(this.resultResponses);" on the handleResponse. It says "Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<any[]>'."

Comment: Ah, my mistake - it's not the observable (`result$`) that does the emitting (`next()`), it's the observer (`resultObs`). Replace that and it should work fine.